# HighCharts use percentage of first column to show percentage of second and third

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have looked everywhere for a solution with no luck. I am trying to get a rainfall chart to be based only on the percentage of the first series of numbers that I plug in. In the code you will see that there are 3 sets of data. The first set is the amount Billed, the second is the amount not collected, and the last is the amount collected. I want to have all the bars based off the first set. so the first group should be based off 522364.0900 being 100%. The numbers for collected can be over but i don't need to show them going over but i would like to show the percentage in the tooltip.

This is [what i am aiming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzi4T.png) for with the data given

This [Grouped Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OZkZ.png) is kind of what I am going for but the bar for Tokyo would be the total amount billed that sets the percentage. so the scale would be to 100% and all the Tokyo bars would go to the top. The other bars are the percentages compared to the billed amount. So if 75% of the billed was collected then it would make the bar for collected 75%. and not collected at 25%. but the confusing part is that the amount collected can be more than what was billed.

I have tried to use grouping and compare but wasn't able to get it to work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
var data = [{
name: 'Amount Billed',
data: [522364.0900, 101354.1100, 119310.1800]
}, {
    name: 'Amount Notcollected',
    data: [-38301.7400, 9674.9700, 919193.5000]
}, {
    name: 'Amount Collected',
    data: [560665.8300, 91679.1400, 1038503.6800 ]
}];

function (data, div) {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: null,
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false,
                        renderTo: div
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Total Billed',
                'Total Collected',
                'Total Uncollected'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}

</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: data
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an illustration of what this would look like? And what you mean by 'rainfall' chart? I am not understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you can use tooltip.formatter in your case: http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#tooltip.formatter, Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/0bgvnscx/1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I have updated my post and added images to it. I hope i explained it better this time.

Comment: You can get the bars to nest like that by setting grouping: false, and providing the same x value for each point, and playing with the pointWidth. But really, this is a a kind of convoluted way to display this data that does more to obfuscate than enlighten.

Comment: The reason behind the way i am wanting to show that way is the numbers are all over the place based on clients and to be able to show all the clients without displaying it like this wouldn't be practical because some of the numbers go into the hundred millions and some in the hundred thousands. so the column for one of the smaller clients may just be a pixel in size while showing the other clients, but if you show the total billed at 100% then they all will match in size. I am not trying to compare the companies just compare collection percentages and be able to show how much each column is.